# parenthesis in make.unique in R

Tags: r, unique, gsub, strsplit

Using `make.unique` function in R will generate the unique variables by appending `.` and indices from 1 like :

```
make.unique(c("a1","a1","a1"))
[1] "a1"   "a1.1" "a1.2"
```

I'm looking for a function that put a parenthesis around the indices like :

```
make.unique.NEW(c("a1","a1","a1"))
[1] "a1"   "a1(1)" "a1(2)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sub` to put parentheses around the number and remove the dot:

```
sub(r"{\.(\d+)$}", r"{(\1)}", make.unique(c("a","a","a", "a1", "a1")))
## [1] "a"     "a(1)"  "a(2)"  "a1"    "a1(1)"
```

The above requires R 4.0.0 or later.  If you have an earlier version of R use this (which also works on R 4.0.0 and later but involves double backslashes).

```
sub("\\.(\\d+)$", "(\\1)", make.unique(c("a","a","a", "a1", "a1")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what if I have a number in the names like the edited version that I have posted

Comment: @Onyambu, Nope : `sub(".(\\d+)$", "\\(\\1)", make.unique(c("a1","a1","a1")))
[1] "(1)"   "a1(1)" "a1(2)"`

Comment: See the revised version.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact match to your desired output, and requires you install a package BUT unlike regex based approaches, this will always work no matter what your input vector looks like

```r
#install.packages('makeunique')
library(makeunique)
make_unique(c("a1","a1","a1"), sep = "")
#> [1] "a1(1)" "a1(2)" "a1(3)"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [makeunique](https://github.com/selkamand/makeunique)